# Recursion error when checking if string is a palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have written down this code which checks whether a string is palindrome or not but on execution the output displays a "recursion error". How can I resolve this issue?

```
def palindrome(string):
    if len(string) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        if string[0] == string[-1]:
            return palindrome(string[::-1])
        else:
            return False

string = input("Enter a string:")
if palindrome(string)==True:
    print("String is palindrome")
else:
    print("String is not palindrome:")
```

Comment: This part: `string[::-1]` is all you need to check if something is a palindrome, you can just `return string == string[::-1]` which will check that a string is the same forwards as backwards.

Comment: If this is supposed to be an exercise, doing [::-1] is not helping at all

Comment: This is probably not related to your problem, but the code in your question had indentation errors. I fixed them, but please make sure your actual code and the question have equivalent indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You had two errors,

The first one is your exit condiction, a string with length of one is supposed to be a palindrome.

Your second error is `string[::-1]` returns the string, but reversed, not reducing the size. You would like to check the string minus the first and the last element, as this : `string[1:-1]`

```
def palindrome(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        if string[0] == string[-1]:
            return palindrome(string[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
string="tacocat"
if palindrome(string): # You should avoid using "if x == True"
    print("String is palindrome")
else:
    print("String is not palindrome:")
```

As mention in the comments, you can also check if it is a palindrome this way `string == string[::-1]` if you don't want to do recursion

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        if string[0] == string[-1]:
            return palindrome(string[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
string=input(“Enter the string”)

if palindrome(string)==True:
    print("String is palindrome")
else:
    print("String is not palindrome:")
```